# how to debug maven plugin source in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I modified a maven plugin source. how to debug maven plugin in eclipse?
mybatis generator plugin,I modified it supports velocity template.I google the question.but result it`s not what I want!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Takari Plugin Testing Project](https://github.com/takari/takari-plugin-testing-project).
It is supposed to supersede the old maven plugin testing from apache.

Personally, i really like it.
Let me know (ask on Github) if you have any issues with it.

Its not limiited to Eclipse IDEs either. It rather gives you a DSL like harness to drive your plugin with different maven versions and combinations.

Give it a try!